# sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, sudo

I am running scans in my Ubuntu machine using `sudo` but it will ask for password to execute it as `root`. But during the runtime its not possible to provide password so is there a way to do so. I mean the password should be passed to the user ROOT.

Comment: Have you tried the accepted answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244898/sudo-a-terminal-is-required-to-read-the-password-either-use-the-s-option-to-r